# in c++ what would happen if we are instantiating an object in global section and the object size is too big?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following example:

```
Foo foo;

int main()
{
    //...
}
```

What would happen if the size of Foo is too big and allocation fails? Consider a small device with limited memory. Also, what difference would it make if Foo is instantiated within main function?

Comment: With some compilation systems you couldn't successfully link.  With others, your program will error in some probably-operating-specific-way when starting.  (On Windows that error might very well occur before you can attach a debugger - and not tell you anything useful about why it errored!  I know from experience...)

Comment: In most modern OSes, you will likely get compiler or linker error.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica - maybe, maybe not.  The object Foo could be small enough to fit in a process space - but too large to fit in memory+swap on some machine you were running on.  That wouldn't be diagnosed by the compiler or linker as it would depend on the configuration of the machine you're running it on.  It could work on some machines, fail on others.  Same, of course, would apply to small embedded systems without swap but with different amounts of RAM.  Anyhow, I'm just objecting to the word "likely".

Comment: @davidbak Right, then it will give out of memory. If Foo is mostly uninitialized, then the out of memory can happen even while the app runs (and its memory area starts being overwritten). If it is uninitialized on the linker level, but is initialized before calling `main()` by its constructor, then it will cause either out of memory or segmentation violation.

Answer (score 0):

> What would happen if the size of Foo is too big and allocation fails?

The language doesn't specify what would happen. This is what the standard says:

> [implimits]
>
> Because computers are finite, C++ implementations are inevitably limited in the size of the programs they can successfully process.
> Every implementation shall document those limitations where known.
> This documentation may cite fixed limits where they exist, say how to compute variable limits as a function of available resources, or say that fixed limits do not exist or are unknown.
>
> The limits may constrain quantities that include those described below or others.
> The bracketed number following each quantity is recommended as the minimum for that quantity. However, these quantities are only guidelines and do not determine compliance.
>
> - ...
> - Size of an object ([intro.object]) [262 144].

The behaviour may vary across language implementations. You can try it out to discover what happens on your target system. Here is a demo where the operating system raises a segfault: https://godbolt.org/z/PjnfbW

Comment: Good!  Answer was kind of useless until you provided the concrete example.

Comment: @davidbak Really? I thought that was least valuable part of the answer since there's no guarantee the example applies to whatever system the reader is compiling for.

Comment: Well the OP didn't ask what the standard said.  And all the standard says is nothing whatsover one way or another. He wants to know what would _happen_.  The godbolt example shows one thing that could _happen_.

Comment: @davidbak The standard is what us programmers rely on to understand how programs will behave. It is what specifies how programs behave. In the case where it doesn't say such as this, we simply don't know, unless we read the documentation of the target system or try it out (latter having a problem that we cannot know whether it always behaves as tested). I already adviced trying it out before adding an example. Even if we don't  know how the program will behave, it is useful to know that we cannot know in general.

Comment: Well, there's no reason to argue about it.  I just think that quoting the standard here to answer the OP's question [was like an old joke everyone's heard](https://funnyjoke.wordpress.com/2006/12/16/technically-correct-but-a-completely-useless-answer/).  I think the godbolt link was to the point.  That's all.

Comment: Hi thanks, I also got a seg fault in my target system, I was concerned if the behavior is actually consistent, so wanted to understand the internal understanding, surprisingly, the code worked when it was instantiated within main.

Comment: @Sourav - If you're able to describe your target system concisely - edit your question to include it! - then maybe we could take a stab at explaining why one worked and the other didn't.  Also - mention this business about it worked inside of main but not global.  That shows additional research for your problem, and makes it more specific, and makes it more likely the question will get good acceptance here by the community.  And how big is a `Foo` anyway?  That's also useful information.